# Why doesn't type deduction work for my set intersection and set difference invocations?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdset, set-operations, insert-iterator

I am trying to write a small algorithm that finds the common and unique parts of two sets and I want to write it in a generic fashion so I have this little example:

```
#include "boost/tuple/tuple.hpp"
#include <set>

template <typename InputIt, typename Value = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>
boost::tuple<std::set<Value>, std::set<Value>, std::set<Value>>
findUniqueAndCommon(InputIt fbegin, InputIt fend, InputIt sbegin, InputIt send)
{
    std::set<Value> setL(fbegin, fend);
    std::set<Value> setR(sbegin, send);

    std::set<Value> uniqueInCatalog1;
    std::set<Value> uniqueInCatalog2;
    std::set<Value> commonInBoth;

    std::set_difference(setL.begin(), setL.end(), setR.begin(), setR.end(), uniqueInCatalog1.begin());
    std::set_difference(setR.begin(), setR.end(), setL.begin(), setL.end(), uniqueInCatalog2.begin());
    std::set_intersection(setL.begin(), setL.end(), setR.begin(), setR.end(), commonInBoth.begin());
    return{ uniqueInCatalog1, uniqueInCatalog2, commonInBoth };
}

int main()
{
     std::set<int> x = {1, 2, 3};
     std::set<int> y = {4, 2, 3};
     findUniqueAndCommon<std::set<int>::iterator>(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end());

}
```

My question is that why does this function fail to compile? I tried gcc, clang and MSVC and they all fail. Clang's error message can be inspected here: 
 https://godbolt.org/g/gFZyzo

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That link just says `<Compilation failed>`.

Comment: if you hover your mouse over the lines showing the error you see the error message @melpomene

Comment: No, I don't. All I get is some "note"s from the middle of an error message.

Comment: The `set_*` functions want an [`OutputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) for the result. (Feel free to remove the irrelevant use of boost from your example.)

Comment: You forgot to #include <algorithm>

Comment: @melpomene godbolt's site ain't workin on mobile, at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)'s usual iterator - [the one you get with `begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin) - is not intended for insertion or deletion, only for traversal of what's in the set. Try an [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) instead:

```
#include "boost/tuple/tuple.hpp"
#include <set>

template <typename InputIt, typename Value = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>
boost::tuple<std::set<Value>, std::set<Value>, std::set<Value>>
findUniqueAndCommon(InputIt fbegin, InputIt fend, InputIt sbegin, InputIt send)
{
    std::set<Value> setL(fbegin, fend);
    std::set<Value> setR(sbegin, send);

    std::set<Value> uniqueInCatalog1;
    std::set<Value> uniqueInCatalog2;
    std::set<Value> commonInBoth;

    std::set_difference(setL.begin(), setL.end(), setR.begin(), setR.end(), std::inserter(uniqueInCatalog1, uniqueInCatalog1.end()));
    std::set_difference(setR.begin(), setR.end(), setL.begin(), setL.end(), std::inserter(uniqueInCatalog2, uniqueInCatalog2.end()));
    std::set_intersection(setL.begin(), setL.end(), setR.begin(), setR.end(), std::inserter(commonInBoth, commonInBoth.end()));
    return{ uniqueInCatalog1, uniqueInCatalog2, commonInBoth };
}

int main()
{
     std::set<int> x = {1, 2, 3};
     std::set<int> y = {4, 2, 3};
     findUniqueAndCommon<std::set<int>::iterator>(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end());
}
```

Note, though, that:

1. You're creating set copies of ranges; I don't think you really need to do that. Just use the ranges - `set_difference` and `set_intersection` actually work on ranges rather than sets.
2. `std::set`s are kept *in-order* by default. Do you need them to be ordered before and after running this code? If not, consider a different choice of containers. On the other hand, as @n.m notes, an ordered container is necessary for `set_difference` and `set_intersection`.
3. You're iterating over both sets three times instead of just once (which you would with a custom function for doing this on ordered containers).
4. The C++ standard has had its own tuple - [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) - since C++11 already.

Comment: Very valid questions, I need them to be set, and yeah I understand I am using set_difference twice. But the set passed in are usually small (less than 20 items) so I am not too worried about it being a bottle neck. Thanks a lot for the quality answer.

Comment: @dorafmon: Remember I'm asking these questions / making these comments not just for your sake, but also for the sake of future readers of your question and my answer.

Comment: set_difference and friends need sorted ranges, so unordered sets won't quite work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to utilize `inserter` because iterators of `set` itself are always const iterators that don't allow value modification:

> ... associative containers where the value type is the same as the key type, both `iterator` and `const_iterator` are constant iterators

```
#include <tuple>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <
    typename InputIt, 
    typename Value = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>
std::tuple<std::set<Value>, std::set<Value>, std::set<Value>> findUniqueAndCommon(InputIt fbegin, InputIt fend, InputIt sbegin, InputIt send)
{
    std::set<Value> setL(fbegin, fend);
    std::set<Value> setR(sbegin, send);

    std::set<Value> uniqueInCatalog1;
    std::set<Value> uniqueInCatalog2;
    std::set<Value> commonInBoth;

    std::set_difference(setL.begin(), setL.end(), setR.begin(), setR.end(), ::std::inserter(uniqueInCatalog1, uniqueInCatalog1.end()));
    std::set_difference(setR.begin(), setR.end(), setL.begin(), setL.end(), ::std::inserter(uniqueInCatalog2), uniqueInCatalog2.end()));
    std::set_intersection(setL.begin(), setL.end(), setR.begin(), setR.end(), ::std::inserter(commonInBoth, commonInBoth.end()));
    return{ uniqueInCatalog1, uniqueInCatalog2, commonInBoth };
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> x = {1, 2, 3};
    std::set<int> y = {4, 2, 3};
    findUniqueAndCommon<std::set<int>::iterator>(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end());
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation. Why can't you use a set as the output?

Comment: @dorafmon I've updated my answer, it was somewhat messed up originally.